# Flask Form Authentication validation with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, forms, validation, flask

Hi there good programmers. I am simply trying to take input from a register form, check and confirm them by validating them against MySQL-workbench database. NB, I am fairly new to Flask and python.

My expectation:

If the input email exist, route and stay on sign up, else route to login.
But the app just keeps on taking inputs and sending them to database, even if it is the same info.

Thanks in advance
Motchello

Here is my code below

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for
from flask import request, redirect
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, CHAR
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# import flask login
from flask_login import UserMixin


# create an inheritance class from DeclarativeBase
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


# instan
db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)

SESSION_TYPE = 'sqlalchemy'
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create a connection to the database using mysql and + pymysql
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/New_User_Database'
# config secrete key
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'TooTopSecrete'

# initialize database app
db.init_app(app)

session = Session(app)


# Create a Table class using flask_sqlaclhemy
class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(CHAR(80))


with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


# view route page for home
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('login.html')


# view route page for login
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')


# view route page for sign up
@app.route('/sign_up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_email = request.form.get('email', False)
        email_in_database = Users.query.filter_by(email=Users.email).first()
        if user_email == email_in_database:
            return redirect(url_for('sign_up'))
        else:
            new_user = Users(
                username=request.form['username'],
                email=request.form['email'],
                password=request.form['password'],
            )
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('login', ))

    return render_template('sign_up.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my sign_up.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Sign up</title>
    <style>

        input[type=email], select {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=password], select {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=text], select {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          padding: 14px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 4px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
          background-color: #45a049;
        }

        div {
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
          padding: 20px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Sign up </h1>

    <div>

        <form method="post" action="/sign_up" autocomplete="on">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="40"
               placeholder="username" autofocus required><br><br>

        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="40"
               placeholder="email" required><br><br>

        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="64" min="6"
               placeholder="password" required><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Sign up"><br><br>
    </form>

        <form method="get" action="{{ url_for('login') }}" >

            <p> Already have an account? <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}"> LOGIN  </a></p><br>

        </form>


    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> login </title>
    <style>

        input[type=email], select {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=password], select {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          padding: 14px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 4px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
          background-color: #45a049;
        }

        div {
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
          padding: 20px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Login </h1>
    <div>
         <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('login') }}" autocomplete="on">

            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="40"
                   placeholder="email" required><br><br>

            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="64" min="6"
                   placeholder="password" required><br><br>



            <input type="submit" value=" Login "><br><br>

        </form>

        <form method="get" action="{{ url_for('sign_up') }}" >

            <p> Don't have an account? <a href="{{ url_for('sign_up') }}"> SIGN UP  </a></p><br>

        </form>

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

I have gone through some stack-overflow answers, and googled around but no avail. All the much help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a body that may help?

Comment: please print these two variables, and see why they are not the same, perhaps one is just lower case or something like that: `print('user email:', user_email)` and `print('email in db:', email_in_database)`

Comment: Hi @Mathias , here is the print out -:   
user email =  mandy@pepcore.com
email in db =  <Users 4>. Thank you

Comment: It seems to be printing out the model and id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is causing the bug:

```
user_email = request.form.get('email')
email_in_database = Users.query.filter_by(email=Users.email).first()
if user_email == email_in_database:
```

Try this instead:

```
user_email = request.form.get('email')
email_in_database = Users.query.filter_by(email=user_email).first()
if email_in_database:
```

Essentially, we just have to check whether the email exists in the SQL DB. We do not need to check a second time (with the `==` operator)

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. I am grateful and humbled. I do believe I will come with more problems in the future but will learn the methods of debugging as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution, change these lines to:

```py
user_email = request.form.get('email', False)
user_from_db = Users.query.filter_by(email=user_email).first()
if user_from_db:
    return redirect(url_for('sign_up'))
else:
    # same code you had before
```

The reason is you were getting a User from the database and calling it an email. But the `Users.query.first()` returns the first User with the email you specified or `None` if it is non-existent.

Then you compared that User with the email, which is not correct, you were basically saying

```
if "my_email@email.com" == None
```

or

```
if "my_email@email.com" == {id:..., email: the actual email, password=""}
```

This is why what I think you were trying to achieve can be done with little change, by fetching that user with the email and then saying

```
if user_from_db:
```

which will be truthy when there is a user, but falsy if it is `None` (no user with that email in database).

There are other things I presume are wrong, you said `filter_by(email=Users.email)` which I'm not sure what does exactly, probably tries filtering by a non-string? It didn't seem to error so who knows, maybe it'll work with your old line. But I changed that to `filter_by(email=user_email)` which is the email from the form. That's saying "get me user from database with the email from the form".

**Some advice:**

- You really need to learn how to debug things like these yourself, look up debugging in python, there are two main ways, using a debugger, like pdb or placing print commands at key points in your program (or both).
- You need to know what is going on in your program, like here, you were trying to compare a string and an object which doesn't make sense, but with some print commands you can see what actually is going on in your program.

Comment: Thank you. this is really helpful. It works, and will highly use your recommended advice.